# Does this function compute convolution correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, convolution

I need to write a basic function that computes a 2D convolution between a matrix and a kernel.
I have recently got into Python, so I'm sorry for my mistakes.
My dissertation teacher said that I should write one by myself so I can handle it better and to be able to modify it for future improvements.
I have found an example of this function on a website, but I don't understand how the returned values are obtained.

This is the code (from http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html )

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
def naive_convolve(f, g):
    # f is an image and is indexed by (v, w)
    # g is a filter kernel and is indexed by (s, t),
    #   it needs odd dimensions
    # h is the output image and is indexed by (x, y),
    #   it is not cropped
    if g.shape[0] % 2 != 1 or g.shape[1] % 2 != 1:
        raise ValueError("Only odd dimensions on filter supported")
    # smid and tmid are number of pixels between the center pixel
    # and the edge, ie for a 5x5 filter they will be 2.
    #
    # The output size is calculated by adding smid, tmid to each
    # side of the dimensions of the input image.
    vmax = f.shape[0]
    wmax = f.shape[1]
    smax = g.shape[0]
    tmax = g.shape[1]
    smid = smax // 2
    tmid = tmax // 2
    xmax = vmax + 2*smid
    ymax = wmax + 2*tmid
    # Allocate result image.
    h = np.zeros([xmax, ymax], dtype=f.dtype)
    # Do convolution
    for x in range(xmax):
        for y in range(ymax):
            # Calculate pixel value for h at (x,y). Sum one component
            # for each pixel (s, t) of the filter g.
            s_from = max(smid - x, -smid)
            s_to = min((xmax - x) - smid, smid + 1)
            t_from = max(tmid - y, -tmid)
            t_to = min((ymax - y) - tmid, tmid + 1)
            value = 0
            for s in range(s_from, s_to):
                for t in range(t_from, t_to):
                    v = x - smid + s
                    w = y - tmid + t
                    value += g[smid - s, tmid - t] * f[v, w]
            h[x, y] = value
    return h
```

I don't know if this function does the weighted sum from input and filter, because I see no sum here.
I applied this with

```
kernel = np.array([(1, 1, -1), (1, 0, -1), (1, -1, -1)])
file = np.ones((5,5))
naive_convolve(file, kernel)
```

I got this matrix:

```
[[ 1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  0. -1.]
 [ 2.  3.  1.  1.  1. -1. -2.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.  0. -3. -3.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.  0. -3. -3.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.  0. -3. -3.]
 [ 2.  1. -1. -1. -1. -3. -2.]
 [ 1.  0. -1. -1. -1. -2. -1.]]
```

I tried to do a manual calculation (on paper) for the first full iteration of the function and I got 'h[0,0] = 0', because of the matrix product: 'filter[0, 0] * matrix[0, 0]', but the function returns 1. I am very confused with this.
If anyone can help me understand what is going on here, I would be very grateful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that function computes the convolution correctly.  You can check this using `scipy.signal.convolve2d`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel = np.array([(1, 1, -1), (1, 0, -1), (1, -1, -1)])
file = np.ones((5,5))

x = convolve2d(file, kernel)
print x
```

Which gives:

```
[[ 1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  0. -1.]
 [ 2.  3.  1.  1.  1. -1. -2.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.  0. -3. -3.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.  0. -3. -3.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.  0.  0. -3. -3.]
 [ 2.  1. -1. -1. -1. -3. -2.]
 [ 1.  0. -1. -1. -1. -2. -1.]]
```

It's impossible to know how to explain all this to you since I don't know where to start, and I don't know how all the other explanations aren't working for you.  I think, though, that you are doing all of this as a learning exercise so you can figure this out for yourself.  From what I've seen on SO, asking big questions on SO is not a substitute for working it through yourself.

Your specific question of why does

```
h[0,0] = 0
```

in your calculation not match this matrix is a good one.  In fact, both are correct. The reason for mismatch is that the output of the convolution doesn't have the mathematical indices specified, but instead they are implied.  The center, which is mathematically indicated by the indices `[0,0]` corresponds to `x[3,3]` in the matrix above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to print each line in the for loops so I can understand it better!

Comment: @Litwos: Thanks for accepting, I shouldn't have been snarky.  In general, it is helpful to accept answers to show others that the question is answered.  (Of course, you shouldn't feel compelled to accept an incomplete or unsatisfactory answer either; though, at the same time, this question was too open-ended to really have a truly complete answer.)